# Get a list of all view functions of a flask app

Tags: flask

Given a flask application, how would you extract all the view functions that end up rendering the results of the requests sent to it?

The reason I ask is because I'm using a flask extension called [flask_apispec](https://github.com/jmcarp/flask-apispec) which requires you to call it with every single function you wish to end up on in the swagger spec and documentation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer was a field named [view_functions](https://github.com/pallets/flask/blob/7e714bd28b6e96d82b2848b48cf8ff48b517b09b/flask/app.py#L401) on the flask application itself.

To produce the api documentation I then ended up iterating over that dictionary:

```
for key, view in app.view_functions.items():
  if key.startswith('api'):
    docs.register(view, endpoint=key)
```

Comment: That gives you a list of view functions, but if the requirement is that they render something (many AJAX handlers don't), then you'll need to dig deeper.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the distinction. Could you give an example of a view function which doesn't render anything?

Comment: Say your web app registers a javascript 'onclick' handler that makes an AJAX call when an icon is clicked. The handler records the click. Good practice would be to return a JSON object noting successful completion, but some people take a shortcut, assuming success. In that latter event, the view's return value (which isn't HTML) is ignored.

Comment: Ah, so you mean endpoints or request handlers which merely return a HTTP response code?

Comment: Yes. It's not a best practice, but it is a fairly common one. Still, if you choose not to do that in your app, that approach is fine.