# Is there a way to convert local flask http request to a function call?

Tags: python, flask, python-requests, request

Currently, in our system, we are calling the endpoints even in the same flask application by a HTTP request. All the requests is called through a make_request wrapper method as shown below:

```
def make_request(url, body, http_type="get"):
    
    http_fn = getattr(requests, http_type)
    response = http_fn(url, headers=headers, json=body)
    return response.status_code, response
```

Hence I'm trying to convert all local requests within the same flask application to a direct method call so that any endpoint within the same flask application is called this way:

```
def make_request(url, body, http_type="get"):
    
    # Figure out If its local request call the function of the endpoint and construct the response
    # If not make an http request
    return response.status_code, response
```

EDIT: Tried searching in the url_map to find the method associated with the endpoint but the function returned in not in a callabale state. Any points on how we can call the method from here?

```
for rule in current_app.url_map.iter_rules():
    if my_url in rule.rule:
       endpoint = rule.endpoint
    
for key, view in current_app.view_functions.items():
    if key == endpoint:
        # Found the view function, need to know how to call 
        # the right method( GET, POST etc)
```

view contains the following:

```
{
'view_class': <class 'endpoints.attribute_endpoints.AttributeEndpoint'>, 
'methods': {'GET', 'PUT', 'POST'}, 'provide_automatic_options': None, '__wrapped__': <function View.as_view.<locals>.view at 0x10c9190d0>}
```

Comment: Whatever you can do in an `HTTP` call, you can do without one. Basically instead of passing a body object in your `POST`, or a header in your `GET`, just pass it to the function directly. And instead of having the `@app.route` function do the function handling, make it call another function that does the job. Example below.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. How do I Identify the function I need to call from the url or the endpoint? Basically instead of making a HTTP request call to http://127.0.0.1/api/route1 I want to be able to detect the route method of this endpoint and call it directly as its in the same server(local)

Comment: If you wrote the code then you should already know. Else scan for the function in the flask apps. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53121934

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, what you're trying to achieve is calling a flask endpoint internally without going over `http`. Look at the solution below and let me know if it is does what you want.

Old Code:

```
@app.route('/someRoute', methods=['GET'])
def some_route_function():
    json_object = request.get_json()
    my_number = json_object['myNumber']
    my_number = my_number**2
    return jsonify(my_number=my_number)
```

New Code:

```
def square_number_func(number):
    return number**2

@app.route('/someRoute', methods=['GET'])
def some_route_function():
    json_object = request.get_json()
    my_number = json_object['myNumber']
    my_number = square_number_func(my_number)
    return jsonify(my_number=my_number)
    

def my_non_flask_function():
    my_number = 17
    my_number = square_number_func(my_number)
```

This way you get the functionality you need without having to rely on Flask's `request` object, nor having to call flask via `http`.

Edit: If you need to figure out if it's an internal flask function then you compare it against a list of functions in your local `global` scope or in your flask `app`, as it does store your `routes`. You can even store the function parameters so you know what to call. Finally, you can map each endpoint to another function if you want inside a dictionary or something, such as `{some_route_function: square_number_func}` so that you can tell which function to substitute for the `http` call.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I'm aware I can call any method inside my function but I want to detect which method to call from just URL

Comment: @GaneshRajasekar As I said earlier, Flask's objects have url mappings. Just get the endpoint you're calling as a string and run it against Flask's url list, which will give you the endpoint + the function.

Comment: Thank you very much. I tried scanning in url_map but the function returned is not in a callable state (from view functions example above). Could you point me to an example of how to scan and call a function from the URL? I have edited my question with what I tried and the returned function

Comment: @GaneshRajasekar Sorry I haven't seen your message. Basically whatever IDE you're using, Control + Click on the "@app.route" function and it will direct you to an internal Flask function that stores all of your endpoints, use that.